# howto force flash bios when a battery is not present

Tags: updates, battery, bios

I have an old dell xps 15 9550 laptop, with the type of battery that inflated and can no longer be replaced. I just installed a fresh ubuntu 22.04 on it, and it notifies me that there is a critical bios upgrade. After installing and rebooting, I come in the bios flash update menu, but it won't flash the update because the battery is at 0% (actually, not present at all).

Is there a way to force the flash anyway? edit: without using windows, I do not have windows. It is an old laptop that I received completely empty.

And, if not, how 'critical' is the firmware update? Perhaps I can just ignore the message?

Additional information: I did find this link https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000134938/forcing-a-bios-update-without-the-ac-adapter-attached-on-a-dell-laptop
so it seems that it should be possible, but that description is about windows and I don't know how to add the 'forceit' option to the linux way of updating the bios.

Answer (score 2):

Flash updating the firmware without the battery could brick the  laptop, so I recommend ignoring the notification that there is a critical BIOS upgrade available except for the following paragraph.

[How to Force a BIOS Update on a Dell Laptop](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000134938/forcing-a-bios-update-without-the-ac-adapter-attached-on-a-dell-laptop) from the official Dell website describes how to update the BIOS (from Windows) on a laptop with or without the AC adapter attached, if the battery is missing or the battery has failed. This would work OK even if you temporarily installed Windows on your laptop and then deleted it when you were finished flashing the BIOS.

Comment: thanks, I understand that it would be risky, perhaps not worth the risk.  But is that only a risk in case I accidentally loose power or pull the cable from the laptop in the process?